# Notification does not play sound in Android

Tags: android, notifications

I have a notification in Android that works well but it does not play the sound i specified to it:

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.code/raw/sound");
```

I know i am not  maybe the first one who had this problem but all the posts i browsed about this did not help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Is any sound playing?

Make sure to not set DEFAULT_SOUND on notification.defaults or the default sound will override your custom sound.

Besides, try to use another Uri format like:

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sound );
```

Comment: No, no sound is playing and i do not have the sound set to default, and i used different Uri formats including your suggestion but i always have no sound playing !!

Comment: So am guessing this was never resolved, its 2020 5 years

Answer (score 1):

```
Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
mBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sound));
```

be sure to have your `sound.mp3` file inside your `/res/raw/` folder.

Comment: I am doing just exactly like you suggest and my sound file is inside /res/raw  but i always have the problem !!

Comment: ok, open your sound.mp3 file and check if it really can be reproduced by a player.

Comment: I did, i opened it with VLC media player and it was played normally with no problem, it has mp3 extension and 71.9 kB of size